# how we can check if file exists in assets folder in swift?

Tags: swift

I want to know how we can check if a file exists in my assets folder for using it in my app.
I know how I can check files in app Bundle with this code, but I do like to check for assets

```
if Bundle.main.url(forResource:ImageName, withExtension: "png")?.isFileURL == true
```

Comment: You mean `xcassets`? `if let myImage = UIImage(named: "myImage") ...`

Comment: I wanted be sure if I have my Image in my assets for using

Comment: That's why this is a [failable initializer](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=17). If the asset doesn't exist it returns nil...

Comment: thanks, Sergio used an UIImage for checking the file, can we use another method like .isFileExists? I mean using a method which supports all kind of files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```swift
let imageExists: Bool = UIImage(named: ImageName) != nil
```